# Dual nature of Matter at gross level

Tags: wave-particle-duality

Is the Dual nature (wave - particle duality) of Matter completely proved or just a theory and are the objects (water,rubber ball, car, apple etc.) that we see all around us in day to day life exhibit dual nature (wave - particle duality) in their natural state of existence (as perceived by the human eye) or only when they are broken down to the molecular level?

Comment: What "dual nature" are you referring to specifically?  From the tag it seems you may be referring to "wave-particle duality;" is that right?  If so, you might want to specify that explicitly in the question.

Comment: Yes, i meant "wave - particle duality" however i was not aware that simply mentioning "dual nature" implies any other phenomena as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the world's biggest Schrodinger cat?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3309/)

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to this.

Firstly, we can steadily increase the size of objects and try to measure quantum properties. At the moment the record is for a [quantum tuning fork](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=quantum-microphone) that contains around 10 trillion atoms. It gets harder and harder to measure quantum behaviour as objects get bigger (for reasons discussed below) but there is no sharp cutoff so there is no indication that baseballs or cars can't (in principle) display quantum behaviour.

Secondly we have a theory called [decoherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence) to explain why it gets harder to measure quantum behaviour as objects get bigger. I don't fully understand decoherence so you'll need to ask an expert for the details. However the basic idea is that any object interacts with it's environment, and this interaction destroys quantum superpositions. The bigger an object, or more precisely the more degrees of freedom it has, the faster the interaction occurs. So we can easily measure quantum behaviour for electrons, but no experiment we can (currently) do can put a baseball in a superposition of states for long enough for us to measure it.

The upshot is that we believe the same equations that describe elementary particles also describe baseballs and cars, but these theories also tell us we'll never see quantum behaviour for such large objects.

Comment: Thank you John, After understanding your response along with some other articles have made things much clearer to me but I am not sure if i am correct in making the following statement

Comment: " the matter contained in day to day objects do not possess wave - particle duality in the state of the object seen by the human eye".

Comment: Yes, your statement is true. However it doesn't embody any great physical insight.

Comment: My thought about this was that wave-particle duality is the fundamental behaviour/property of all matter hence it exists in all states of existance of matter, all that is required is to prove it experimentally for larger objects. However it seems that it is not true.

Comment: @user33587: Wave/particle duality **is** a fundamental property and **does** apply to all matter. However at the scale we can see with the naked eye quantum superpositions don't last long enough for us to be able to measure them. That's why I added the caveat that your statement doesn't embody any great physical insight. Although we'll never be able to prove it for large objects, we understand this is due to [decoherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence) and not because of any fundamental restriction.