# What is the largest Schrödinger's cat-like experiment ever set up?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, history, schroedingers-cat

I guess largest in this context either means something like the most massive or containing the most states.

Comment: see this article: https://www.quantamagazine.org/real-life-schrodingers-cats-probe-the-boundary-of-the-quantum-world-20180625/ from June 2018.  See also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3309/  as an older question from 2011.

Comment: Schrödinger's cat is not a meaningful experiment. You set it up, you open the box, if the cat is alive, what have you proved? Nothing. If the cat is dead, what have you proved? Nothing. Schrödinger's entire point was to highlight the foolishness of philisophical arguments over what we can say about the state of the system in the box when nobody knows the state of the system in the box.

Comment: A more meaningful question would be what are the largest objects for which entanglement has been observed. As far as I know, the current record is held by K.C. Lee et al., "Entangling Macroscopic Diamonds at Room Temperature." Lee's thesis describes the experiment and is not paywalled. It can be found by googling: "Generation of room-temperature entanglement in diamond with broadband pulses," Oxford, 2012.

Comment: @SolomonSlow ... not so sure about your comment.  See https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00107514.2016.1261860 or its arXiv version https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.05322.pdf.  Although describing proposals, the paper does point to serious efforts to produce meaningful superpositions.  To quote: "Remarkably, recent developments in quantum optomechanics and electromechanics may lead to the realisation of quantum superposition of living microbes soon".

Comment: If QM is fundamental, than the Universe.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Hmm... I see... I'm afraid it could take some time and effort on my part before I will be able to understand exactly why the proposed virus-particle-in-an-optical-trap demonstration would be more satisfying or more meaningful than the cat-in-a-box demonstration.