# What method scientist use to conclude that a particle is on superposition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition

I have seen documentaries, news, and general public reports among other things, that express the conclusion of particles like electrons  super position can be at two places at the same time, but i haven't been able to find the details of the experiment and the tools used to reach to this conclusion.
My hypothesis is that there is missing information that could be leading to a wrong conclusion. I suspect that super position is the result of a delay on the perception of the particle location that result in detecting the particle in two locations in one frame.

Just like a slow camera that can't keep up with the motion frames, causing a blur and extended image. If this hypothesis is true, our interpretation of quantum physics could change dramatically.

Comment: It is none of those things. It is not about a delay or about missing information. The idea of position being a well-defined internal property of a particle is in itself incorrect. A particle has no position or momentum intrinsically.

Comment: This question could be fine if the body was edited to actually ask a question. Right now it seems too much like "I have a theory..."

Answer (score 2):

You can read about canonical experiments like:

- The [Hong-Ou-Mandel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect) experiment.  There are also YouTube videos like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8wP4V5GDTI) or [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld2r2IMt4vg) but just searching for HOM experiment in Google will return multiple hits.  The possible outcome of a scattering experiment is dictated by the amount of superposition of wavepackets inside an inteferometer.
- This is also a "dual" experiment to HOM where sources are superposed: the Pfleegor-Mandel experiment.  No video on this but it is discussed [in this blogpost](https://scienceblogs.com/principles/2010/11/19/interference-of-independent-ph).  Basically the setup produces a single photon from *two* independent but superposed lasers, and one can recover interference.
- There are also examples of microscopic quantum superpositions, as described for instance [here](https://www.iflscience.com/physics/over-half-meter-record-macroscopic-quantum-superposition/).  There are even experimental realizations of the famous Schrodinger's cat experiment, as discussed [in this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3309/36194)
- You might even consider [Rabi oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabi_cycle) as an example of the evolution of a state initially in a superposition of eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.  In this example, an initial state oscillates between two eigenstates and this just described by a superposition of these eigenstates.  [Neutrino oscillations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation) are in the same family of effect, where the evolution of an initial state is described by a superposition of two other states.

The list of experiments verifying superposition is very long.